# How to tie dark mode with prefers-color-scheme webkit?

Tags: plugins, css, jquery

I implemented dark mode on my Wordpress website with the following code:

```
    //Create the cookie object
    var cookieStorage = {
        setCookie: function setCookie(key, value, time, path) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + time);
            var pathValue = '';
            if (typeof path !== 'undefined') {
                pathValue = 'path=' + path + ';';
            }
            document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';' + pathValue + 'expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
        },
        getCookie: function getCookie(key) {
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
        },
        removeCookie: function removeCookie(key) {
            document.cookie = key + '=; Max-Age=0; path=/';
        }
    };

    //Click on dark mode icon. Add dark mode classes and wrappers. Store user preference through sessions
    $('.dark-mode-button').click(function() {
        //Show either moon or sun
        $('.dark-mode-button').toggleClass('active');
        //If dark mode is selected
        if ($('.dark-mode-button').hasClass('active')) {
            //Add dark mode class to the body
            $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
            cookieStorage.setCookie('siteDarkMode', 'true', 2628000000, '/');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('dark-mode');
            setTimeout(function() {
                cookieStorage.removeCookie('siteDarkMode');
            }, 100);
        }
    })

    //Check Storage. Display user preference 
    if (cookieStorage.getCookie('siteDarkMode')) {
        $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
        $('.dark-mode-button').addClass('active');
    }
})
```

Now I want to tie this script with prefers-color-scheme webkit, so it would work together. The code I provided stores user settings via defined cookie, so prefers-color-scheme should respect that. But if user didn't define his preferred style (dark or light), the script should take into consideration his OS settings.

Does anyone have any idea how can I modify this code to make it work like that? I'm not sure what's the best approach.

Thanks,
Kacper

Comment: I don't see how this is related to WordPress, this looks like a generic CSS/JS question